# Django Template Does not exist with string literal

Tags: django, django-views, view

Inside Django I have a template that when specified explicitly with

return "letter.html" -- everything works as expected

```
class letterView(PDFTemplateView):


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        letterID = self.kwargs['letterID']
        object = get_object_or_404(djangoLetters, id=letterID)
        return super(letterView, self).get_context_data(object=object,**kwargs )

    def get_template_names(self):
        letterID = self.kwargs['letterID']
        letterType = djangoLetters.objects.get(pk=letterID).letterType
       #template_name = str(letterType.letterBackgroundBase)
        template_name = "letter.html"
        return template_name
```

However, when I use str(letterType.letterBackgroundBase) which returns letter.html -- I get an error saying that the Template can not be found for "letter.html".

I expect the problem has something to do with unicode literals, but I've tried importing the future unicode line at the top of the service/view as well as using django's smart_str built in utilities.

The file is definitely there and works when called explicitly, but when it's coming from an object, even though "letterType.letterBackgroundBase" returns back "letter.html" something is still failing.

Any thoughts?

```html
class djangoLetterTypes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID',primary_key=True)
    letterBackgroundBase = models.CharField(db_column='LETTER_BACKGROUND_BASE',max_length=60,null=False,blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME',max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    letterCode = models.IntegerField(db_column='LETTERCODE',max_length=50,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'djangoLetterTypes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class djangoLetters(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID',primary_key=True)
    letterType = models.ForeignKey(djangoLetterTypes,db_column='letterType',to_field='letterCode')
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'djangoPDFLetters'
```

[Image link for Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stg07.png)

Comment: Could you provide your `djangoLetters` model?

Comment: I added the models -- although, still the end result in the debug error message says that it can't find template "letter.html"

Comment: Done some searching https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names . Could you return a list, like so `return [template_name]`

Comment: That is how I had it at first. It works with

return [template_name]
return template_name
return "letter.html"

Comment: Just doesn't work with return [template_name] when template_name = str(letterType.letterBackgroundBase)

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: https://sentry.io/share/issue/3132303333302e313937303335303731/

Comment: what happens with template_name = '{}'.format(letterType.letterBackgroundBase) and return [template_name]

Comment: Same thing -- here is stack trace:
https://sentry.io/share/issue/3132303333302e313937303335303731/

Comment: is there any space at the end of the string? if yes, strip the space: `letterType.letterBackgroundBase.strip()`

Comment: ... Not sure how I've been so stupid. Thank you so much @Enix